# How to write an equation in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, calculator, equation

I am trying to write an equation that has two inputs and one known value to give me a answer.
For example x * C * .053 = Y. I followed a tutorial on how to make a simple multiplication calculator and it worked

```
@implementation CalculatorViewController

-(IBAction) calculate {

float x = [textField1.text floatValue];

    float c = x*([textField2.text floatValue]);


    label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", c ]; 


}
-(IBAction)clear {
    textField1.text = @"";
    textField2.text = @"";
    label.text = @"";
}
```

My problem is how can i input a known static (.053) value into the code and multiply it to the x * c  values that need to be inputed by the user and get an answer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
float c = x*([textField2.text floatValue]);
```

To this:

```
float c = x*([textField2.text floatValue]) * 0.053;
```

Writing equations in programming is pretty similar to writing them in math.

Comment: ".053 Is never valid in Obj C" - it is. It's perfectly valid C.

Comment: Its working but not giving me number after decimal point in the answer for example i put in 5 * 5 * 0.0519 and it just gives me the answer 1.

Comment: I figured this out.  %f formats number with 6 decimals versus %0.f which always formats the number to the nearest whole.  @implementation calViewController

-(IBAction)calculate {
    float x = ([textField1.text floatValue]);
    float c = x*([textField2.text floatValue]) *0.0519;
    
    label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%f", c];
}

-(IBAction)clear {
    textField1.text = @"";
    textField2.text =@"";
    label.text = @"";
}

Comment: @H2CO3: Got rid of it. Thanks.